# unable to load Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll with nuget package : Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, tfs

I want to create a library with visual studio/c# using TFS API for create / update workitem.

I added nuget package "TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient" to my library and I have the following error when I try to access to WorkItemStores:

> Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore64.dll.

It's working when I try directly on my console application, and it's not when I referenced it on my library and called it from my console application.

Another strange things it's that dll is correctly in my bin folder ( Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll and Microsoft.WITDataStore64.dll).

I try to reinstalled TFS in my local environnement, reinstalled NuGet package, try on another library, it's still not working.

```
        tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(uri)); // https://mytfs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
        tfs.Authenticate();

        var workItemStore = new WorkItemStore(tfs);
```

Anyone with a solution or at least a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the solution,
here the workaround if this can help :

the dll need to be referenced on the console application calling the library.

We can do that with xcopy command in your library postbuild command.

Add this ( replace TestConsoleApp with your name application )  :

xcopy *.* $(SolutionDir)TestConsoleApp\bin\Debug\ /Y /R

Enjoy.

EDIT : this is not a clean way to fix it ,instead I used different way to create a work item, we can find microsoft documentation here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/quickstarts/create-bug-quickstart?view=azure-devops